# How can I create new array of similar key value pair?

Tags: javascript

```
0: {indexofitem: 0, indexofchild_1: 0, name: "dfds", setName: "SET A", quantity: 2, price: 500,…}
1: {indexofitem: 0, indexofchild_1: 1, name: "bvcxvb", setName: "SET B", quantity: 2, price: 500,…}
2: {indexofitem: 0, indexofchild_1: 2, name: "vcx", setName: "SET C", quantity: 2, price: 500,…}
3: {indexofitem: 1, indexofchild_1: 3, name: "vxc", setName: "SET A", quantity: 1, price: 500,…}
4: {indexofitem: 1, indexofchild_1: 4, name: "vcx", setName: "SET B", quantity: 1, price: 500,…}
5: {indexofitem: 1, indexofchild_1: 5, name: "cxvxz", setName: "SET C", quantity: 2, price: 500,…}
```

How can i create new array of similar key value pair(indexofitem)? in general not based on 0 or 1.. it can be anything.

I want two arrays of object...

```
0: {indexofitem: 0, indexofchild_1: 0, name: "dfds", setName: "SET A", quantity: 2, price: 500,…}
1: {indexofitem: 0, indexofchild_1: 1, name: "bvcxvb", setName: "SET B", quantity: 2, price: 500,…}
2: {indexofitem: 0, indexofchild_1: 2, name: "vcx", setName: "SET C", quantity: 2, price: 500,…}
```

and

```
3: {indexofitem: 1, indexofchild_1: 3, name: "vxc", setName: "SET A", quantity: 1, price: 500,…}
4: {indexofitem: 1, indexofchild_1: 4, name: "vcx", setName: "SET B", quantity: 1, price: 500,…}
5: {indexofitem: 1, indexofchild_1: 5, name: "cxvxz", setName: "SET C", quantity: 2, price: 500,…}
```

Comment: question and problem is not clear. So is the expected result

Comment: @brk Question updated hope it makes sense..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the index property and push to the sub array while reducing the data.

Methods used:

- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with an array as accumulator `r` and the object `o` as item,
- a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) for checking if the property is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and if not take an array.

```js
const
    array = [{ indexofitem: 0, indexofchild_1: 0, name: "dfds", setName: "SET A", quantity: 2, price: 500 }, { indexofitem: 0, indexofchild_1: 1, name: "bvcxvb", setName: "SET B", quantity: 2, price: 500 }, { indexofitem: 0, indexofchild_1: 2, name: "vcx", setName: "SET C", quantity: 2, price: 500 }, { indexofitem: 1, indexofchild_1: 3, name: "vxc", setName: "SET A", quantity: 1, price: 500 }, { indexofitem: 1, indexofchild_1: 4, name: "vcx", setName: "SET B", quantity: 1, price: 500 }, { indexofitem: 1, indexofchild_1: 5, name: "cxvxz", setName: "SET C", quantity: 2, price: 500 }],
    result = array.reduce((r, o) =>
        ((r[o.indexofitem] = r[o.indexofitem] || []).push(o), r), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thankyou so much... Can u provide any link to understand more about this method. MDN only contains basic information.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it. using filters we can do as follows:

```js
const items = [
 {indexofitem: 0, indexofchild_1: 0, name: "dfds", setName: "SET A", quantity: 2, price: 500},
 {indexofitem: 0, indexofchild_1: 1, name: "bvcxvb", setName: "SET B", quantity: 2, price: 500},
 {indexofitem: 0, indexofchild_1: 2, name: "vcx", setName: "SET C", quantity: 2, price: 500},
 {indexofitem: 1, indexofchild_1: 3, name: "vxc", setName: "SET A", quantity: 1, price: 500},
 {indexofitem: 1, indexofchild_1: 4, name: "vcx", setName: "SET B", quantity: 1, price: 500},
 {indexofitem: 1, indexofchild_1: 5, name: "cxvxz", setName: "SET C", quantity: 2, price: 500}
];

const indexofitems0 = items.filter(item => { return item.indexofitem === 0});
const indexofitems1 = items.filter(item => { return item.indexofitem === 1});

console.log(indexofitems0, indexofitems1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as i said I want more generalised answer... not based on 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

```js
bitArray = [
    {indexofitem: 0, indexofchild_1: 0},
    {indexofitem: 1, indexofchild_1: 1},
    {indexofitem: 0, indexofchild_1: 2},
    {indexofitem: 1, indexofchild_1: 3},
    {indexofitem: 0, indexofchild_1: 4},
    {indexofitem: 1, indexofchild_1: 5},
];
result = {};
bitArray.forEach((item) => {
    if (!result[item.indexofitem]) {result[item.indexofitem] = [];}
    result[item.indexofitem].push(item);
});
// 0 indexes
console.log(result[0]);
// 1 indexes
console.log(result[1]);
```

Comment: @KunwarSagar ... this approach is an example of how not to use `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are new to JavaScript. Now, this is very simple solution using forEach:

```
const items = [
    {indexofitem: 0, indexofchild_1: 0, name: "dfds", setName: "SET A", quantity: 2, price: 500},
    {indexofitem: 0, indexofchild_1: 1, name: "bvcxvb", setName: "SET B", quantity: 2, price: 500},
    {indexofitem: 0, indexofchild_1: 2, name: "vcx", setName: "SET C", quantity: 2, price: 500},
    {indexofitem: 1, indexofchild_1: 3, name: "vxc", setName: "SET A", quantity: 1, price: 500},
    {indexofitem: 1, indexofchild_1: 4, name: "vcx", setName: "SET B", quantity: 1, price: 500},
    {indexofitem: 1, indexofchild_1: 5, name: "cxvxz", setName: "SET C", quantity: 2, price: 500}
];

//object with indexofitem value as key and list of all items with same value indexofitem as value
let indexofitemObjs = {};
items.forEach(item => {
    indexofitemObjs[item.indexofitem] ? indexofitemObjs[item.indexofitem].push(item) : indexofitemObjs[item.indexofitem] = [item]
})

Object.keys(indexofitemObjs).forEach(indexItem => {
    console.log(`Array List of: ${indexItem} : \n ${JSON.stringify(indexofitemObjs[indexItem])}`)
})
```